# Remove row by row number in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a very simple function that will take the dataframe and row number as arguemnts, and then return a dataframe without that row. So if I have:

```
1 ben
2 adrian
3 bill
4 matthew
```

After calling remove(3,df) I will get:

```
1 ben
2 adrian
3 matthew
```

Anyone can help out?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you can use e.g. `df[-3,]` to remove row 3 from the output? (or in case of multiple rows to be removed: `df[-c(1:2),]`)?

Comment: @beginneR, he will need `, drop=F` too in order to keep it in a `data.frame` structure, but that's basically it

Comment: I want to permantently remove it from the dataframe and then save it to rda file

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, to permanently remove it, use `df <- df[-3,, drop=FALSE]` and then save it as you wish.

Comment: @beginneR, actually akrun already demonstrated it

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the point I was trying to make was mainly that I don't think a custom function is necessary for this (but that's personal preference)

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, I think that you are asking if this possible to do this *by reference*, well I don't think so. It maybe be possible in the future using the `data.table` package, as it already possible for columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is all you really need

```
> removeRows <- function(rowNum, data) {
      newData <- data[-rowNum, , drop = FALSE]
      rownames(newData) <- NULL
      newData
  }
> dat
#        V2
# 1     ben
# 2  adrian
# 3    bill
# 4 matthew
> removeRows(3, dat)
#        V2
# 1     ben
# 2  adrian
# 3 matthew
```

Answer (score 4):

This function can be written as a one-liner (albeit without error checking):

```
remrow <- function(x, rows) x[-rows,, drop = FALSE]
```

Here's your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
rownames(dat) <- c("ben", "adrian", "bill", "matthew")
```

`remrow(dat, 2)` will strip out the "adrian" row, while `remrow(dat, 1:2)` will remove both the "ben" and "adrian" rows.

Note that `is.data.frame(remrow(dat, 1))` evaluates to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

If `df` is the dataset

```
fun1 <- function(data, rowN){
 indx <- !(seq_len(nrow(data)) %in% rowN)
 data1 <- data[indx,, drop=F]
 row.names(data1) <- seq_len(nrow(data1))
 data1
 }

fun1(df, 3)
#       V1
#1     ben
#2  adrian
#3 matthew

fun1(df,1:2)
#       V1
#1    bill
#2 matthew
```

Comment: Why are you using `row.names` here? All he wants is a row number. It is quite possible that the `row.names` won't fit the row number. I don't think anything else but `data[-rowN,, drop=F]` is needed in this function

Comment: @David Arenburg, I changed row.names to `1:nrow(data)`.  Yes, you are right. there may be cases with different rownames.

Comment: @beginneR. You are absolutely correct.  Thanks for your comments.  Updated the code.

Comment: `rownames(data) <- NULL` will reset the row names to a sequence also.